# Diablo 3 Amiibo Portal - Is there a limit?

Tags: nintendo-switch, diablo-iii-console, amiibo

I want to know whether the Amiibo portals in Diablo 3 Switch re-stock themselves or not.

Like, if I have 3 Amiibo portals, and I used all of them today, would I get new ones tomorrow? Does it replenish or is it a permanent object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to restlessness, I found out that the Amiibo Portal would not be affected in any way other than the fact that you will have to wait for a set amount of time after using it... fortunately...